# d3 x axis not starting at 00:00 but instead at 02:00

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm physically sitting in GMT+2.
D3 version: `3.5.17`

The first date object I have is the following: `2018-09-13T00:00:00.000Z`

The last date object I have is the following: `2018-09-13T23:00:00.000Z`

```
const xmin = '2018-09-13T00:00:00.000Z';
const xmax = '2018-09-13T23:00:00.000Z';
d3.time.scale().nice()
    .range([0, options.width])
    .domain([new Date(xmin), new Date(xmax)]);
```

I would like for the graph displayed to me to have the x-axis as the following:

```
00 ..... 23
```

I am currently getting:

```
02 ..... 01
```

It is taking my GMT+2 into consideration which I do not want. I want it to display UTC. I understand this is an issue with Javascript Date objects. I have absolutely no idea however how I am to fix this with D3. The documentation is *horrendous*.

I tried putting the ISO string in, but results in NaN:

```
const scale = d3.time.scale().nice();



const _xmin = '2018-09-13T00:00:00.000Z';
const _xmax = '2018-09-13T23:00:00.000Z';
scale
    .range([0, options.width])
    .domain([_xmin, _xmax]);

const _response = scale(_xmin);
console.log({
    _response
});



const __xmin = new Date('2018-09-13T00:00:00.000Z');
const __xmax = new Date('2018-09-13T23:00:00.000Z');
scale
    .range([0, options.width])
    .domain([__xmin, __xmax]);

const __response = scale(__xmin);
console.log({
    __response
});
```

Console:

```
{_response: NaN} // <--- not working
{__response: 0} // <--- working
```

Comment: which d3 version are you using?

Comment: @Shushan version: "3.5.17"

Comment: do all your time stuff in UTC, in d3v5 it is possible, you have all the UTC versions of the needed functions in d3

Answer (score 0):

You can use this to get the UTC format.

```js
const xminutcDate = (new Date('2018-09-13T00:00:00.000Z')).toUTCString();
const xmaxutcDate = (new Date('2018-09-13T23:00:00.000Z')).toUTCString();

console.log(([xminutcDate, xmaxutcDate]));
```

Comment: Hi man! I did try using strings but then: `d3.time.scale().nice()` doesn't seem to work, just returns `NaN`? When I use a Javascript Date object it works though :/

Comment: `.domain(['asdasdaaa', xmaxutcDate]);` <-- for example gives no error, which is stupid.

Comment: Updated with an example.

Answer (score 0):

You can try setting a `UTC` time scale like so:

```
d3.time.scale.utc().nice()
    .range([0, options.width])
    .domain([new Date(xmin), new Date(xmax)]);
```

Comment: I'm afraid to say that did not fix the issue :(

Comment: Sorry. A fiddle would really help.

Comment: Yea I should fix one, it's however in really complicated/messy code, I'll see what I can do about it, thanks for the help anyway!

Answer (score 0):

Ok So this apparantly worked, I have no idea why though:

```
const parseDate = d3.time.format("%Y-%m-%d %X").parse;
xmin = parseDate(moment.utc(xmin).format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss"));
xmax = parseDate(moment.utc(xmax).format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss"));
```